# Trying to assemble a Hex dump utility but it gives Undefined symbol?

Tags: linux, assembly, nasm, undefined-symbol

I'm starting to learn x86 assembly and was trying to make a simple HEX-dump utility that take input from stdin and write it back to as hex values to stdout. But every time i try to assemble NASM tell me that I have 3 errors first one is undefined symbol.which is this line`and bl, F0h` which i cant see what's wrong in it.

Comment: Numbers have to start with a digit, otherwise the assembler thinks it's a symbol. Use `0F0h`.

Comment: @jester ohh, it worked now thank's alot